# Why does $\log_{4}32 \neq \log _{4}(4 \cdot 8)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\log_{4}32=2.5$$

If  $$\log_{a}(b\cdot c) = \log _{a}b + \log_{a}c \,\,\,; (a>0, b>0,c>0, a\neq 1)$$

Then why does $\log_{4}32$ can't be $\log _{4}(4 \cdot 8)= \log_{4}4+\log_{4}8 = 1+2=3$?

Comment: Because your computation of $\log_4 8$ is incorrect.

Comment: sorry for that miss :(

Comment: $\log_4 8 = \log_4 2^3 = 3\log_4 2 = 1.5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $\log_4(8) \neq 2$.  Instead, $4^2=16$.

Comment: woow what a miss :(